# How to develop a Marathi language website?

Tags: html, multilingual

I want to develop a Marathi language website. The website will be dynamic, giving the user the ability to provide feedback or comment in Marathi.

I want to develop the site in HTML5 using PHP as the server side language. I used   tag but still it's not working..

Also I used Google hindi/marathi font for displaying Marathi on the  website.

So, please anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: processwire.com/api/multi-language-support/multi-language-fields/ this may help

Comment: http://gate2home.com/Marathi-Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it from here 
http://www.quillpad.in/hindi/demo-editor.html

it can really help you

jai Hind

Comment: Hey, thanx sahil.but, i don't want to buy any editor. i'm trying google phonetic but it's not supported by all browser's.